# Page in web browser appears different compared to Internet Explorer in emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am loading a login page (webpage) in Windows Phone web browser control in my application. On clicking the Login button a popup appears and overlay is set (css/jquery) to the background so that other buttons can't be accessed. Now the problem is when I click Login button, popup appears and the background becomes black (javascript is enabled). Also, the same page is loading fine in Internet Explorer in Windows Phone emulator.

I am a Windows Phone developer I dont have much idea about scripting languages. Please advice me.

I am loading the webpage like

```
 {
 Initializecomponent();
 webBrowser1.Loaded += WebBrowser_OnLoaded;
}
       private void WebBrowser_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {         
  webBrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = true;
                Modules.Userloginurl = Modules.Userloginurl + Modules.deviceId +   "&platform=phone7&market_id=";
                webBrowser1.Source = new  Uri("http://demo.rifluxyss.com/T3/pawebsite/index.php?deviceid=1&platform=iphone&market_id=CA", UriKind.Absolute);
}
```

Comment: Add code you want us to review. We can't help without looking at it.

Comment: hey volgin,I have added the code!

Comment: It seems the page runs in quirks mode. I would recommend to test it in IE9 desktop first (for example fontface is not supported). Also unable to repro your problem  since the page layout was just changed and there is not Login button right now.

Comment: The page is good in IE8 and all browsers including browser in emulator.